# How do I resolve error in date conversion in Java?

Tags: java, date

[image]
I'm working on a project which interacts with different components.
My doubt is with respect to two components: `OrderHandler` [Springboot] and `OrderHandler-projections` [Flink].

I have a DTO customized for date, which is named `WorkingDateDTO` and is used across different components.
`WorkingDateDTO` is a date DTO which has a `LocalDate` wrapped inside it
as follows:

```
public class WorkingDateDTO {
  private LocalDate date;

  public LocalDate getDate() {
    return this.date;
  }

  public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
```

And this is the event sent from `OrderHandler` component.
`Order` component sends a `OrderEvent`. It has a `Order` date of type `WorkingDateDTO` (which is customized as per the working date of my

```
public class OrderEvent {
  private String orderId;
  private String orderType;
  private String orderCode;
  private WorkingDateDTO orderDate;
}
```

Now this event is received by `OrderHandler-projections`. So when it's received in `OrderHandler-projections`, there is an error in a few test cases.

The test cases use generator class which generates different orders for testing the code and business logic.

```
WorkingDateDTO workingDateDTO = new WorkingDateDTO();
LocalDate date = dateGenerator.generate(random,status).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
// This is converting date into local date as Java's default dateGenerator will give you a "Date". 
//But we need "LocalDate" which is wrapped inside "WorkingDateDTO".
workingDateDTO.setDate(date); // Setting localDate in WorkingDateDTO
orderEvent.setOrderDate(workingDateDTO);
```

I can't understand what the problem is.

```
Error: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected error in property revertTheLastOrderDateIfAReversalOrderIsSent with args
```

`revertTheLastOrderDateIfAReversalOrderIsSent` calls `prepareReversedOrder` method which throws an error when I run in debug mode.

```
private OrderEvent prepareReversedOrder(OrderEvent orderEvent)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    OrderEvent event =
        mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(orderEvent), OrderEvent.class);
    event.setOrderType("_reversal_");
    event.setOrderId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    System.out.println("$$ prepareReversedOrder - Event  :  " + event);
    return event;
}
```

Comment: > "there is an error in a few test cases"
Please show us the smallest test case that fails and the error you're getting. The code you showed looks OK to me.

Comment: DST (daylight saving time) can play havoc with tests, in Europe between 02:00 and 03:00. For instance if you _parse_ `"02:30"`. With date times I have often found checking code to be wrong, on time unit boundaries, and more.

Comment: @JoopEggen So how do I resolve it?

Comment: Using Random makes tests a minefield. The failed tests should provide enough info to recreate them with fixed values, and then you might see the conceptual error and may repair your algorithm. Keep this case as separate unit test too. _For the rest I cannot help._

Comment: Right, I'll look into all this and alter the code accordingly. I found this helpful.